# Weird C++ linked list bug

Tags: c++, macos, x86, segmentation-fault, paging

I tested this code snippet on different machines with GNU in different versions, only one bizarre Mac with Clang 1001.0.46.3 reports segmentation fault. Is there any address problem or pointer problem in this piece of code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    Node* next;
    int val;

};

class List
{
private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
public:
    List()
    {
        head = tail = nullptr;
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(!head && !tail) return true;
        return false;
    }
    void pushBack(int num)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->val = num;
        if(isEmpty()) head = tail = newNode;
        else
        {
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = tail->next; 
        }
    }

    void pushFront(int num)
    {
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->val = num;
        if(isEmpty()) head = tail = newNode;
        else
        {
            Node* tmp = head;
            newNode->next = tmp;
            head = newNode;
        }
    }

    void popBack()
    {
        if(head == tail) {delete head; head = nullptr; return;}
        Node* tmp = head;
        while(tmp->next != tail) tmp = tmp->next;
        tail = tmp;
        delete tmp->next;
        tmp->next = nullptr;
    }

    void popFront()
    {
        if(head == tail) {delete head; head = nullptr; return;}
        Node* tmp = head;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        delete head;
        head = nullptr;
        head = tmp;
    }

    int findLen()
    {
        if(isEmpty()) return 0;
        int len = 0 ;   
        Node* tmp = head;
        while(tmp)
        {
            len++;
            //if(tmp == tail) break;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        return len;
    }

    void inserter(int position, int num)
    {
        if(position > findLen() || isEmpty()) return;
        int index = 0;
        Node* tmp = head;
        Node* newNode = new Node;
        newNode->val = num;
        if(position == 0) {pushFront(num); return;}
        else if(position == findLen()) {pushBack(num); return;}
        while(tmp->next)
        {
            index++;
            if(index == position)
            {
                Node* tmp2 = tmp->next;
                tmp->next = newNode;
                newNode->next = tmp2;
                return;
            }   
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }

    void print()
    {
        if(isEmpty()) return;
        cout << "list = ";
        Node* tmp = head;

        while(tmp)
        {
            cout << tmp->val << " ";
            if(tmp == tail) break;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{   
    cout << "delete added" << endl;
    List testList;
    testList.pushBack(5);
    testList.pushBack(10);
    testList.pushBack(15);
    testList.pushBack(20);                          // after this line, we got segmentation fault
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    testList.pushFront(5);
    testList.pushFront(10);
    testList.pushFront(15);
    testList.pushFront(20);
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    testList.inserter(0,8);
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    testList.inserter(9,555);
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    testList.inserter(5,333);
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    cout << "popBack" << endl;
    testList.popBack();
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    cout << "popFront" << endl;
    testList.popFront();
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    cout << "popBack" << endl;
    testList.popBack();
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    cout << "popFront" << endl;
    testList.popFront();
    cout << "len = " << testList.findLen() << endl;
    testList.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Follow up: Hey, guys, I just got some clues by myself. I think the problem should be on the OS side. After check the related assembly code, I noticed that even though I got default initialized value as 0 for local variables, they are not ALWAYS zero. I think the problem should be the paging scheme of the OS. I will do my best to figure out how MacOS (kernel 10.15.1) and linux pick page and how the random value generated for local variables. If anyone knows about this area or has any clue to figure it out, feel free to let me know. Cheers.

Comment: I just dont know what else I need to say, there is not error info on my machine, I help other one debug this code, the only error info he got was Segmentation fault (11). No particular GDB error info attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think next would be initialized as nullptr by default.

**Only static storage is zero-initialized by default and safe to read even without any explicit initializer.**

Dynamic and automatic storage can and do hold random garbage (in theory and in real implementations).

In practice the first few dynamic allocations may also be zero-initialized because the allocator has to get a new page from the OS. But after deleting some objects and allocating more, you're recycling memory from the free list.  (Unless the CRT startup code already did that before the top of `main`, in which case even the first small allocation will get dirty memory.)

Tools like valgrind can help identify reading uninitialized memory.

MSVC's debug mode also has a useful feature for this: it fills "uninitialized" variables with a recognizable poison value, memset(0xCC) which isn't a valid pointer, and which (if executed as x86 machine code) is an `int3` instruction: debug breakpoint. And in other contexts (like as an integer) tends to be recognizable.

> After check the related assembly code, I noticed that even though I got default initialized value as 0 for local variables, they are not ALWAYS zero. I think the problem should be the paging scheme of the OS.

New pages of anonymous memory *from the OS* are always zeroed to avoid leaking potentially-sensitive information between users.  (e.g. a page previously used to read the contents of `/etc/shadow` or an ssh key).  This applies when `new` has to use `mmap` or `brk` behind the scenes to get more memory, or the *first* time a function call decrements RSP down into a new page.

Usually you aren't getting a fresh page, you're reusing an already-allocated page (via the free list, or for the stack by reusing memory that a previous function call dirtied).  Unless your function is the deepest the callstack has ever been, expect dirty memory.

Your experiment that saw mostly zeros in uninitialize variables was probably the only thing your program did, and thus was the first time callstack got that deep.

Or for dynamic allocation, probably there was no dirty memory in the free list so `new` had to get a new virtual page from the OS.

---

The size of pages merely determines *when* the logically-zero stack and BSS get physically zeroed, and with what granularity.

Based on comments on another answer, I think you're getting hung up on the mechanism that OSes use to do zeroing.  "Getting more pages" as a concept makes sense and is useful to think about for dynamic storage, but is confusing you for the stack.

Static storage and stack space have a fixed layout.  The stack frame for a function call goes right below the frame for its parent, and is freed when it returns.  The callstack *is a stack data structure*.

So what matters is whether this is the deepest you've ever been in the stack; page boundaries are irrelevant.  A function doesn't dirty a whole page of stack space when it runs, it only dirties the memory it actually uses.  The stack is typically limited to something like 8 MiB, with only a few 4k pages of that in use by the time CRT start code calls `main`.  So you basically have most of an 8MiB array of zeroed memory as stack space.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that in each `Node` the `next` member is not initialized.

Uncomment your commented line
`//if(tmp == tail) break;`
in method `findLen` is a solution too.

The right way to fix this issue is to re-write your Node class as

```cpp
class Node
{
public:
    Node* next = nullptr;
    int val;

};
```

Anyway i hope this is just homework or an exercise, otherwise go for the good old `std::list`.

Comment: I think next would be initialized as nullptr by default.

Comment: @Edee well, it's not. Indeed you are also initializing `head` and `tail` in your `List`

Comment: I run it on my platforms in both linux and mac with several GNU in different version. All give me default value as nullptr. On my friend's platform, situation seems different. When he initialized global variable, default val would be 0, as for local variables, default values are random. But on my side, they both 0. I just want some clue to figure it out? Why this happens?

Comment: You should never get as assumption that variables will be initialized for you. Always initialize them explicitly.
Maybe you are building a debug build that apply some memory safety rule.

Comment: @Edee: Only static storage is zero-initialized by default and safe to read even without any explicit initializer.  dynamic and automatic storage can and do hold random garbage (in theory and in real implementations).  In practice the first few dynamic allocations will also be zero-initialized because the allocator has to get a new page from the OS.  But after deleting some objects and allocating more, you're recycling memory from the free list.)  This probably explains why your experiment failed to see garbage in malloc/new results.  Stack space may also be zero on the first deepest call

Comment: @Edee: tools like valgrind can help identify reading uninitialized memory.  MSVC's debug mode also has a useful feature for this: it fills "uninitialized" variables with a recognizable poison value, `0xCC` which isn't a valid pointer, and which (if executed as code) is a debug breakpoint. And in other contexts tends to be recognizable.

Comment: Thx, I know the rules of POD initialization. I'm now kinda curious about the paging scheme of Linux and MacOS, it seems like linux is more safe, cuz it can handle uninitialized pointer type to nullptr, but I am still not quite sure yet, i'm currently checking the disassemble code, and try to get some clue, if you have any telling underlying theory, I truly yearn to know.

Comment: @Edee: *cuz it can handle uninitialized pointer type to nullptr* This is only maybe true by luck for allocations made before deleting anything, if you're talking about memory from `new` being zeroed.  Linux and MacOS are not fundamentally different in any way for this, just maybe different special-case behaviour due to different libc startup code.  e.g. maybe MacOS allocates something and frees it, leaving some non-zeroed memory in the free list.

Comment: ok, I got some idea from your answer. One more thing, is this kinda coincidence relevant to the size of the physical memory? For example, if the resource is so limited and the allocator can not get new page from OS at once, the rate of 0 default initialization for local variable is gonna be rare , am i right?

Comment: @Edee: no, the total size of physical memory is irrelevant.  Perhaps you mean that the page size is much larger than the stack frame of most functions?  That's also not relevant, what matters is whether you've used that specific memory before or not.  The callstack *is a stack* that pops off stack frames when a function returns.